# ON UPDATE CASCADE Giving unexpected error

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a bunch of alter table statements and I need to add a `on update cascade` to certain columns.  When I run the script I get:

```
An unexpected token "CASCADE" was found following "ON UPDATE".
Expected tokens may include:  "RESTRICT, NO ACTION".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.17.30"
```

My statements are all like this:

```
ALTER TABLE integ ADD FOREIGN KEY (planner) REFERENCES g_secure(planner) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

What do I need to change to fix the statement ?

Comment: I don't seem to have problems with this syntax (ON UPDATE CASCADE) - I think you'll need to show the relevant creates or maybe provide a fiddler link to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use MySQL syntax with DB2, which is not valid. DB2 does not support `CASCADE` on an `UPDATE` (search for `rule-clause` on [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-5-6-26&lang=en)).

If you are indeed using DB2 (and I'm assuming you're using DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows here), then this should be the correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE integ 
    ADD CONSTRAINT foreign_key_name
    FOREIGN KEY (planner)
        REFERENCES g_secure(planner)
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: It's not MySQL syntax, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is standard SQL syntax (which DB2 does not have, as you have shown.)

Comment: @ypercube He had the question tagged with [tag:mysql], so I made an assumption. You are right, of course.

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I can believe that DB2 does not support that, and this is part of the SQL 92. Now, I do not trust when IBM says it is SQL 92 compatible.